# Phabricator feed.http-hooks not notifying

Tags: phabricator

I am trying to setup Slack notifications for Phabricator using [etcinit/phabulous](https://github.com/etcinit/phabulous). However, Phabricator does not seem to be notifying the server.

My config looks like this:

```
{
feed.http-hooks: [ "http://127.0.0.1:8085/v1/feed/receive" ]
}
```

If I run `curl http://127.0.0.1:8085` from within the server I get

```
{"messages":["Welcome to the Phabulous API"],"status":"success","version":"2.4.0-beta1"}
```

I am running Phabulous in debug mode, but I can see no request is ever made to 127.0.0.1:8085 since Gin shows no debug message.

Am I missing some configuration in Phabricator to actually made `feed.http-hooks` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to restart the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Above configuration didn't work for me, but this works:

> {"feed.http-hooks":"https://callback_domain.xyz"}